# EF6 Add an ObjectSet based on an existing ObjectSet

Tags: entity-framework-6, objectcontext, objectset

I have an EF6 ObjectContext containing a largish number of ObjectSets.

One EntityObject in particular has over a hundred properties, including some large text fields.

I have several forms to work with, that work with different pieces of the data.

Rather than have to load the entire object definition, is there a way I can define a "new" EntityObject that contains the primary key, timestamp, and a half dozen text fields, so that only those fields get pulled from the database?

I'm asking this because I've already got a databinding, validation and update pattern already built up for this, and I'd rather not have to build a second one to go alongside it.

Comment: Use ViewModels. Automapper is a great companion for doing this sort of thing.

Comment: still,he needs to load the entities first..

Comment: Look at "table splitting".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, Hope it helps

1- Define a new class with the properties you want to store

2- write your sql/linq query to pull the fields you want from your db..

Say your table with over 100 properties is `USERS` table, now define another class

```
class TEMP_USERS{
    int U_ROWID {get;set;}
    string U_NAME {get;set;}
}
```

your query:

```
var query = "SELECT U_ROWID, U_NAME FROM USERS"
```

then store it in the defined class like this:

```
var db = new yourDbContext();
var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<TEMP_USERS>(query).ToList();
```

Note: selected query **types** and **names** should match with the defined class in order for this to work.

after you do this set your databindings accordingly but you will need to manually handle data validation and other stuff

Comment: Thanks Asim.  However, I've got ObjectContext (EF6), and that doesn't have a "Database" property.

Comment: Why not use the DbContext? one other way is you could go old school, run query, get results and match and store them in TEMP_USERS class.. or if you would like to have something generic(This one is a bit nasty) you would get resutls and result properties from the sql query, and create dynamic classes at runtime